# Regexp ignore certain parts in string

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to use regex for a string to find matching results.
I need to find the (.+?) but would like to ignore everything where it says (*) right now:

```
$regex='#<span class="(*)"><a href="/venues/(*)">(.+?)</a></span>#';
```

Instead of ignoring (* ), it echoes out what is in (* ).

How can I ignore these and only get (.+?) ?

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesizes mean *capture*: what's inside those `()` will be *captured* so you can use it later.

If you do not want something to be *captured*, because you don't want/need to use it later, just remove the parenthesizes.

<sub>I should add that using regular expressions to extract data from HTML is generally quite not such a good idea... You might want to use a DOM parser instead, with [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) for example .</sub>

Comment: thank you - the point is also that there will be something inside class="", e.g. class="example" and I need to tell regex that it should ignore what is inside the quotes, in this case example - any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can use something like `.*?` without having to capture what it matches ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That worked. I will add the solution to the question.